# Listwise learning to rank with negative sample relevance

Tags: machine-learning, ranking

Typical listwise learning to rank (L2R) algorithm tries to learn the rank of docs $\{x_i\}_{i=1}^m$ corresponding to a query $q$. If we use correlation efficient to label the relevance between docs and query, then the label $y_i\in[0, 1]$. The larger the $y_i$, the more relevant of the doc $x_i$ to $q$. Most L2R algorithms, such as approximated rank/NDCG and ListMLE, focus more on the ranking accuray of positve correlated doc (i.e. $y_i$ close 1) by giving larger weight in the loss function. This is common in information retrieval problem.

However, if the relevance between docs and query can also be negative, i.e. $y_i\in[-1,1]$, and the ranking accuaracy of both large positive and large negativa docs are important, how can L2R algorithms handle this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

As you mention L2R losses put higher weight on the most relevant documents.
If you want to put high weights on both the most relevant and the least relevant documents, you need to create a new loss for that purpose.
A simple option would be the sum of two existing L2R losses, one with $y_i$ and one with $-y_i$.